# How to increase paramiko performance

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a performance issue with Paramiko, I did many tests and I don't know how to fix it. I have a script running many commands to an external SSH server, it works fine, but it's very long because of a time.sleep(1). So the script does nothing during 1 second after each command sent.

At the moment, it sends 17 commands, so the user is waiting something like 23s. According to the command, the script doesn't need to wait 1s, so I would like to know when the scripts ends to receive data from server then directly send a new command.

I tried to check in Channel.recv or BufferPipe, but it didn't work.

You will find below how I send commands:

```
         for command in commands:
            try:
                chan.send(command)
                while chan.recv_ready() is False:
                    time.sleep(1)
                output += chan.recv(2048)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with that code:

```
         for command in list_commands:
            try:
                chan.send(command)
                while chan.recv_ready() is False:
                    time.sleep(0)
                while chan.recv_ready():
                    output += chan.recv(2048)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
```

I won 13s for 16 commands, it looks worth.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit status of the command - no need to use time.sleep.
One possible solution:

first, define a function to connect to the ssh server:

```
def createSSHClient(server, port, user, password):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, user, password)
    return client
```

create that client:

```
some_command = 'YOUR_COMMAND'
sshClient = createSSHClient(host, port, username, password)
```

Execute the command and check its exit status

```
   stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command(some_command)
   if (stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0):
     print "command failed"
   else:
     print "command succeeded"
```

Comment: Your code won't work, you can use exec command only one time else you have to open a new channel, anyway I will try to do it with several channels.

Comment: Indeed - I used multiple multiple channels (I had the same case where i had to execute few commands). I remember when i had problems with the exit code, i added sshClient.exec_command(some_command,get_pty = True)
But not sure if this is the solution here. This is the best i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem may be related to paramiko itself. While writing a program to check the status of ten servers for about a dozen parameters, I found with even parallelising the ten checks, it was taking about 9-10 seconds. When I replaced paramiko with ssh via subprocess.check_output, performance improved to about 2 seconds.

Here's the key parts, including parallelisation:

```
def ServerSummary(sinp):
    server,ip=sinp.split('|')

    def Remote(cmd, IP, user='root'):
        cmd='''ssh %s@%s %s'''%(user, IP, cmd)
        lines = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split())
        return lines

    tcp=Remote('ss -s|grep TCP:',ip).split()
    tcp=str(tcp[1])
```

.
.
. # Other status information is collected and returned as a tab-separated string.

```
    return '''%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s'''% (server,
    html,mysql,memcache,PD,DBStatus,tcp,load1,load2,load3,size,used)
```

.
.
. # This is the main part that gets the list of servers and their IPs and launches the routine to collection information per server, in parallel. When all the information has been collected, it is sorted by server name and printed out.

```
Sout=[]; S=[]
for Owner in ['MyServers','YourServers']:
    Servers=GetActiveServers(sids=[Owner])
    for server,ip in Servers:
        if server in ['INFRARED',]: continue
        s='%s|%s'%(server,ip)
        S.append(s)

from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(len(S))
Sout.append(p.map(ServerSummary, S))

Sout=sorted(Sout[0])
for i in Sout: print i
```

This is a sample of the output:

```
time python CheckAllServersTSV.py 
Server  HTML MySQL Memc ProcD QPS TCP Load1 Load2 Load3 Disk Used
ServerD ok  ok  NO  ok  6.303   14  0.09    0.06    0.03    20G 38%
ServerE ok  ok  NO  ok  7.131   27  0.16    0.28    0.48    20G 30%
ServerI ok  ok  ok  NO  13.52   161 0.05    0.01    0.00    35G 23%
ServerJ ok  ok  NO  ok  4.629   62  0.00    0.02    0.01    56G 27%
ServerK ok  ok  NO  ok  3.169   13  0.05    0.01    0.00    35G 17%
ServerL ok  ok  ok  ok  2.621   17  0.05    0.05    0.04    35G 35%
ServerM ok  ok  NO  ok  0.043   13  0.07    0.10    0.06    35G 13%
ServerQ ok  ok  NO  NO  1.074   15  0.05    0.01    0.00    35G 14%
ServerP ok  ok  ok  NO  2.230   33  0.08    0.03    0.02    35G 25%
ServerR ok  ok  NO  ok  0.856   11  0.05    0.01    0.00    35G 11%

real    0m2.079s
user    0m0.628s
sys 0m0.780s
```